# Twitter bootstrap icons are not loading in Firefox & IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, icons, sprite

In rails 3.2.9, i am using twitter bootstrap plugin but in Firefox(both in Linux & Windows) & IE(in Windows) icons are not loading. In chrome & chromium icons are loading fine.

In Linux, Firefox version is 20.0 & in windows, IE version is 9 & 10.

My bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file contains,

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white");

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
// Note: If you use asset_path() here, your compiled bootstrap_and_overrides.css will not
//       have the proper paths. So for now we use the absolute path.
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.svg");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome";

// Glyphicons
//@import "twitter/bootstrap/sprites.less";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is this in production or development?

Comment: This issue is in both production & development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Glyphicons image and put it in your asset folder,then call it .

```
  @iconSpritePath: asset-path("/assets/glyph-iconset.png");
  @iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("/assets/glyph-iconset-white.png");
  // Glyphicons    
  @import "twitter/bootstrap/sprites.less";
```